# 'wget' call had nonzero exit status - R - Linux RHEL 7

Tags: r, rhel, install.packages

I try installing some required packages in R, which I just installed on a Linux machine. I am unable to install any package and get the below warning:

```
> install.packages("mongolite", repos="https://cran.r-project.org", lib="/opt/app/workload/deployments/installables/R-3.5.0/Rpackages")
^C


^CWarning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  'wget' call had nonzero exit status
Warning message:
package ‘mongolite’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)
```

I had to press ^+c after waiting for about 30 mins.

The same is the case with 'curl', but without the wait of 30 mins.

The following is the output of sessionInfo():

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.4 (Maipo)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /.../R-3.5.0/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /.../R-3.5.0/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0 tools_3.5.0
>
```

I am unable to understand what is blocking the packages to be installed. Please help.

Thank you

Comment: Does the computer use a proxy to connect to the internet?

Comment: Yes, it does. But process wise, it is difficult to get the details. So is there any work around?

Comment: If you have some other R installation with normal internet access you can adept this: https://www.google.de/amp/s/www.r-bloggers.com/installing-packages-without-internet/amp/. If your only working internet connection is via the unknown proxy you will have to download all required packages manually from CRAN.